# Sharepoint Pagetitle

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Standard sharePoint just put "Page - some site" in the page title in the browsers, but I want to change that, but don't know how.

I have succesfully created a webpart to do so, but I believe it's a major overkill creating a webpart to control such a small part of something as huge as SharePoint.

So how can I control what the page title in best practice?
Is a webpart reallly neccessary or can this goal be achieved in some other way?

To specify some more: I don't want it to just have the same title all over the site. I want it to say something like: "AwesomeSite - Home" or "AwesomeSite - Video upload" etc. You get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question , where would these keywords like `AwesomeSite, Home, Video Upload` come from ? What would be the source?

The best would be to create a `Delegate` Control and refer it in your master page. This delegate control can be either a simple javascript to set the Title or a web server control which will query the sharepoint metadata on current page to set the Title.

Comment: I was thinking about using the parent web as a resource using its title, that's kind of what I did with the webpart I made.

Comment: Created a delegate control as you suggested and put in the code I had in my webpart and it now works perfectly. Thank you.