# Change PageTitle on SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to change the page title.
My actual title looks like this.

**MyWebsite - page**

if I have a page url like this:
www.mywebsite.com/SitePages/apple.aspx

My page title will look like this:

**MyWebsite - apple**

I've created a custom list. Which stores the Page Title.
I can get it like this.

```
<SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="CustomPageTitle" runat="server"/>
```

But I cannont delete this Code, it brings me an error.

```
<SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:PageTitle>
```

How is it possible to Change the page title?

**Note:**

- I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013
- I'm trying to Change it on MasterPage. Not a Wepart.
- [I've read the Post, but it didnt help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862216/sharepoint-pagetitle)

Comment: do you want to do this in a code?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use a WebPart, I want to do it directly on the MasterPage(SharePoint aspx)